# Change the package name in App details

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to change the name of a android application, and also its package name.

I am using [Diawi](http://diawi.com) to generate link of apk and test it on phone. I have changed the package name in manifest file, yet when I check the app details before installing apk file on mobile, it shows the previous name.

Can anyone tell me where to update the name of the application, so that it shows the new name in app details?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: Do you mean app name or package name or application id? If you wish to change app name that users see, change the application android:label in the manifest.

Comment: Package name that is displayed in app Detils page of an apk

Comment: if you want change the name of project than do one thing in manifest file in application tag `android:label="ChangeYourAppNameHere"`

Comment: I want to change package name which is displayed in app details of apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change default config in your app level `build.gradle` as follows:

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        applicationId <new-package-name>
        ...
}
```

Comment: Have been doing this. Not working. Should have, but not. Clean and rebuilt as well. Do you know why is that happening?

Comment: Just Invalidate cache and restart the studio

Answer (score 0):

In your app folder, you will find `build.gradle`, You can search for `applicationId` to change your package name

`applicationId "your.app.id"`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.app.id"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

If you want change application name, Goto `AndroidManifest.xml` file and you can change it by renaming Application label

`android:label="@string/app_name"`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  ....

 </application>
```

Hope this helps